# Create classes in a loop

Tags: python, class, scikit-learn

I want to define a class and then make a dynamic number of copies of that class.

Right now, I have this:

```
class xyz(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.model_type = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()
        self.model_types = {}
        self.model = {}
        for x in range(0,5):
            self.model_types[x] = self.model_type

    def fit_model():
        for x in range(0,5):
            self.model[x] = self.model_types[x].fit(data[x])

    def score_model():
        for x in range(0,5):
            self.pred[x] = self.model[x].predict(data[x])
```

I want to fit 5 different models but I think Python is pointing to the same class 5 times rather than creating 5 different classes in the model dictionary.

This means that when I use the "score_model" method, it is just scoring the LAST model that was fit rather than 5 unique models.

I think that I just need to use inheritance to populate the model[] dictionary with 5 distinct classes but I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: Do you really mean 5 different classes, rather than 5 different _instances of the class_?

Comment: Also, what makes you think inheritance would help here? Inheritance is how you make a class that's a subclass of another—e.g., if `Spam` inherits from `Meat`, then any `Spam` object is also a `Meat` object, and can be used anywhere a `Meat` object is needed. I'm not sure how that would do you any good here—but if you can explain how you think it would, that might make it clearer what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: I am not sure which I need and my thought on inheritance was just a guess.  Maybe I do just mean instances of the class but I need them to be separate instances so that when I run score_model() it scores 5 unique models rather than the last model which was fit.

Comment: Yes, those are separate instances of the same class—or, put in more concrete terms, separate models of the same model type. So tmrlvi's answer is exactly what you want. (What you actually asked for is also doable, but it's a bit more complicated…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your orignal code, you created one instance and used it five times. Instead, you want to initialize the class only when you add it to the model_types array, as in this code.

```
class xyz(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.model_type = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier
        self.model_types = {}
        self.model = {}
        for x in range(0,5):
            self.model_types[x] = self.model_type()

    def fit_model():
        for x in range(0,5):
            self.model[x] = self.model_types[x].fit(data[x])

    def score_model():
        for x in range(0,5):
            self.pred[x] = self.model[x].predict(data[x])
```

In python everything is an object, so your variable can point to a class as well, and then your variable can be treated as a class.

Comment: How does this work if I need to feed options as well?  ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=10)

Comment: You can create the options in a dictionary like `options = {'max_depth' : 10}` and pass it as keyword arguments using the `**` sign, like `self.model_type(**options)`. Remember that it you want different options, you'll need to create different dictionary for each one.

Comment: More information about **kwargs: https://freepythontips.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/